# Threads and Events Handler Android

Tags: android, multithreading

In my Android application, I started a thread in the onclick of button. The thread is working fine.

I want to prevent the user from clicking the same button again before the first response is received. It causes the start of another thread. Please help me with thread and event handling in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also make sure that only "one" instance of the thread can be opened. For this you have to do the following.

```
public class ThreadClass{
    private static ThreadClass instance;

    public static ThreadClass getInstance(){

        if(instance == null){
            instance = new ThreadClass();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private ThreadClass(){
    //Set the constructor to private
    }
}
```

Then you can acces the tread-instance with

```
private newThread= ThreadClass.getInstance();
```

And so it is also ensured that only one instance of this thread exists.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a boolean variable like

> isFirstThreadEnded = false;

and add a method

```
public void onFirstThreadEnded {
isFirstThreadEnded = true;
}
```

and make the thread call this method when he finish its first round.
and on the onClick event check if that value is true before running.

that just a sinnpet, you should make a bit more complicated to handle the first click before the first thread has been loaded but it's the idea in general

an exmaple:

In your thread :

```
private IntentService myIntentService;

public MyThread (IntentService intentService) {
 myIntentService = intentService;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
//do your thread stuff
//when finished call onFirstThreadEnded inside myIntentService
somecode()
myIntentService.onFirstThreadEnded();
}
```

in your IntentService:

```
private boolean isFirstThreadEnded = false;

public void startThread()
{
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (isFirstThreaEnded)
            new MyThread(this).start();
  });
}

public void onFirstThreadEnded()
{
 isFirstThreadEnded = true;
}
```

it should be something like that... but you still need to handle the first thread running because the default value of isFirstThreadEnded is false;

Comment: can you explain little more please?? I am starting a thread from intent service.

Comment: i've actually never used an Intent Service but the mechanism should be similar:
i'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the button disable the button by using `button.setEnabled(false)` and at the end of thread enable the button by using `button.setEnabled(true)`

Hope this helps you